# table-cell css margin and borders interference

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a webpage with css-only layout that always fits in 100% of the screen window. To do that a display table is extensively used as in the example below. However, when multiple table-cells are placed next to each other in columns the margin/border/padding of one will affect the margin/border/padding of the other. How can I make them independent?

In the code below, the "central" margin shifts down the div in the "side" cell, while the margin-top of the div in the "side" cell has a strange behavior. The wanted result is to set independently the aside logo margin and the border of the content.

```
<div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="mainContent">
     <div class="side"><div class="sidewrapper">
        <div class="title">Aside logo</div>
        <div class="sideText">Aside text</div>
     </div></div>
<div class="central">
   <div class="article1">
      article1
   </div>
   <div class="article2">
      article2
    </div>
   <div class="article3">
      article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 article3 
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">footer </div>


html, body {
  display:table;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
.header {
  display:table-row;
  background: red; width: 100%; height: 20px;
}
.footer {
  display:table-row; height: 20px;
  background: red; width: 100%;
}
.mainContent {
  display: table;
  height:100%; width: 100%;
  background:gray;
}
/***********************/
.side {
  width:200px;
  display:table-cell;
  background: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sidewrapper{ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  display: block; 
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
.title{
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: block;
}
.sideText{ height: 50%;
  margin: 5px; background: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
/***********************/
.central {
  padding: 1px;
  background:yellow;  display:table-cell;
  border: 20px solid blue;
}
.article1 {
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.article2 {
  height: 75%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.article3 {
  height: 15%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Enialis/L5kdb4t5/2/

Comment: I can't follow what your'e saying, so take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/L5kdb4t5/3/ and tell me if that's close or not.

Comment: Thanks for the code. To see my problem try to put  margin-top: 140px; in .title class....why article 1 is going down as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `vertical-align:top` setting of the .side and .central div elements. Otherwise the table-cells will try to vertical align the first lines of their text content.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the problem

Comment: This helped me a lot as well. Thank you! I forgot about this property.